# How to set keyboard shortcut using Shift+(any latter) without interfere on default behaviour (type upper case latter)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, xubuntu, shift

My system is Xubuntu 16.04.5 and I would like to ask if is possible to set keyboard shortcut using Shift+(any latter)? I tried and the shortcut works but now I can't type upper case latter ( in case used for this shortcut). So, does it possible to have this shortcut keeping the default behavior of Shift key? thanks, vladi

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. A shortcut is either there and does its job, or it isn't.

Better use a shortcut using Ctrl-Shift or anything else.